# how to import the following csv into mysql, using mysql commands?

Tags: mysql, text, csv, data-import

How to import the following csv into a mysql table, using mysql commands?

```
##
#File name : proj.csv
 #line 1 are the field headers
 #record 1 starts at line 2, ends at line 583
 #from line 2 "<!DOCTYPE" to line 582 "</html>" are actually text blob of
 #record 1 's "html" field
##

line 1: "proj_name","proj_id","url","html","proj_dir"
line 2: "Autorun Virus Remover",1,"http://www.softpedia.com/get/Antivirus/Autorun-Virus-Remover.shtml","<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"">
line 3: <html>
line 4: <head profile=""http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"">
...
line 582: </html>
line 583: ","Antivirus/Autorun-Virus-Remover"
```

The trouble is that the target csv file has a text blob field (named "html", which contains text with multiple lines) in it, so I can't use a '\n' to be the record seperator, or it will say "Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns". A thousand thanks !!!

Comment: Have you triied to separate fields with other character not used in the html? maybe | (pipe)

Comment: Thanks, but the target file is already there (given by my boss), and it has thousands of records like this, I think to replace all the sepearators is as difficult as the import problem itself.